# PHP htaccess URL rewriting

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess

I am currently writing an app where you can add a comment to a post based on IdTicket.

`<td><a href="comment.php?IdTicket=<?php echo $data['IdTicket']; ?>">Comments</a></td>`

I am passing the Id value in my URL which is a part of the table. It is a dynamic value, different for every ticket. I am using $_GET['IdTicket'] on the comment.php page to get the id and based on that write a comment.

Is there a way to rewrite that link in htaccess? It would be perfect to hide everything or just make it prettier. And how would it look applied to that table?

Comment: why use .htaccess for that when you can write your url using php as you want it..

Comment: How would you do it? Sorry new to php

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Sure that is possible. And there are already countless examples for this...

You need to change the reference you hand out in your spplication logic:

```
<a href="comments/<?php echo $data['IdTicket'];?>">Comments</a>
```

And you need to take care to internally rewrite the incoming request to the actual resource again:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?comments/(\d+)$ /comments.php?IdTicket=$1 [QSA,END]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded. And if you want to use distributed configuration files (instead of the real host configuration inside the http server) you also need to have enabled the interpretation of those for host and location.